# strengthening Lesbegue Number Lemma

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $F : I \times I \rightarrow X$ be a continuous map and U, V be two open covers of X. Then Lesbegue lemma says that there exist partitions of I which are $0=s(0)<...<1=s(m)$ and $0=t(0)<...<1=t(n)$ such that each rectangle $R(ij) = [s(i), s(i+1)] \times [t(j), t(j+1)]$ of $I^2$ is mapped into $U$ or $V$.

Now the question is : Is it possible to claim that the edges of R($ij$) are included in the intersection of $U$ and $V$? And if possible, how to do it?

I know the process when $F$ is just a path from $I$ to $X$, but can't extend the method when $F$ is given as above. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I edited your post -- please make sure I didn't alter the meaning (it wasn't obvious how to parse it).

Comment: oh by the word 'x' I meant a cartesian product. The rectangle R(ij) is a cartesian product of two closed intervals.